# Trivia Game building almost finished, How to check the users guess and return it true cross referencing the object index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem here is that i've been unable to find out what's making my game not 'tock(expression). I have used many resources including `console.log()` and cross referencing my data. Even looking into other games that have a guess checker. Mine just seems to not be working. I created a jsfiddle so that all the resources are available. https://jsfiddle.net/ufpxchg2/ my `guessChecker` should be working properly so that the buttons light up green when the answer is right also my `.score-container` seems to not be showing up as i would like it to at the end of the game.

Comment: "'Tock"? Can you elaborate on this? The jsfiddle just seems fine, but unpolished.

Comment: it's not reading my incorrect/ correct guesses. 'tock is an expression. user clicks an answer, its supposed to show either red or green and store that variable but it's not doing that.